# Chakra-UI custom font not rendering

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to add a custom font by extending the theme in chakra-ui but the font doesn't render.

This is my custom theme and i pass it to the chakra provider .

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "@fontsource-variable/nunito-sans";

const myTheme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    body: `'nunito-sans', sans-serif`,
    heading: `'nunito-sans', sans-serif`,
    mono: "Menlo, monospace",
  },
});

export default myTheme;
```

What i've noticed is that the theme does change, while the fallback font (sans-serif) gets applied custom font (nunito-sans) doesn't.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Fontsource docs](https://fontsource.org/fonts/nunito-sans/install), use `'Nunito Sans Variable'` for the font name instead of `'nunito-sans'`.